# How to correctly display jQuery Ajax Error response text as Alert

Tags: json, django-views, jquery-ajax

I am trying to create an *alert* from an ajax callback error using:

`alert(response.responseText);`

However I get the whole string of error text like eg.

`"{\"form_error\": {\"__all__\": [\"Data with this Doc and Date already exists.\"]}}"`

which is being returned by my **Django view**.

My ajax function looks like:

```
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url :  ...,
        dateType: 'json',
        data: my_data,
        success : function(response){
             ...
        },
        error : function(response, status, error){
            var err = response.responseText;
            alert("Error: " + err);
        }
        });
```

Is there a way to only display the relevant text to the user as `alert` for example:

```
err = "Data with this Doc and Date already exists."
    alert(err);
```

**How can I display only the relevant info as alert?** *In my search for a possible solution I have been through numerous SO posts including ways to **extract the substring** of the above response text but nothing has worked.*

PS. I tried to use regex on the Django view side but I could do that with multiple iteration and finally could only come up with:

`{"Error": "Data with this Doc and Date already exists"}` *[Note the curly brackets]*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you receive as an error response is a json string. It is a stringified json object. You have to parse it to get an acces to json properties. After this you can join all errors messages from array that contains error messages ( in this case only one, but since it is an array it can contain more then one)

```
const err= JSON.parse(response.responseText).form_error.__all__.join("\n");
alert(err);
```